# One-to-many: on insert from somewhere appears unknown column with EF core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I have simple one-to-many relations.

```
public partial class LinkedDocument
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }

    public virtual TblDocumentData Document { get; set; }
}

public partial class TblDocumentData : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // other props
    public virtual ICollection<LinkedDocument> LinkedDocuments { get; set; } = new HashSet<LinkedDocument>();
}

modelBuilder.Entity<LinkedDocument>(
        entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("LinkedDocument");

            entity.HasKey(e => new {e.Id, e.DocumentId})
                  .HasName("PK_LinkedDocument")
                  .IsClustered(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Document)
                  .WithMany()
                  .HasForeignKey(d => d.DocumentId)
                  .HasConstraintName("FK_LinkedDocument_TBL_DocumentData_DocumentId")
                  .IsRequired()
                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
```

and for TBL_DocumentData fluent api (only part)

```
entity.HasMany(d => d.LinkedDocuments)
                      .WithOne(d => d.Document)
                      .HasForeignKey(d => d.DocumentId)
                      .IsRequired();
```

On Save I have code like this:

```
this._ctx.Set<TblDocumentData>().Add(documentData);
this._ctx.Set<LinkedDocument>().Add(new LinkedDocument {Id = attachmentModel.EntityId, DocumentId = documentData.Id});
await this._ctx.SaveAsync(cancellationToken);
```

but on save I see error: Invalid column name 'TblDocumentDataId'.
From debug console I can see that SQL script is generated like this:

```
INSERT INTO [LinkedDocument] ([DocumentId], [Id], [TblDocumentDataId])
      VALUES (@p22, @p23, @p24);
```

Searching by solution - cannot find column `TblDocumentDataId` - so this is something added by EF.

What I missed in configuration of my one-to-many relation?

Comment: What is the point of `entity.HasKey(e => new {e.Id, e.DocumentId})`?

Comment: @GuruStron, by some reason it's a combined PK...

Comment: I was asking for the reason=)

Comment: As for problem try changing `entity.HasOne(d => d.Document).WithMany()` to `entity.HasOne(d => d.Document).WithMany(data => data.LinkedDocuments)` and you can remove the setup from `entity.HasMany(d => d.LinkedDocuments)` (I would argue that there is no point to setup the same twice)

Comment: @GuruStron, to have only unique documents linked to some entity (id is like indirect FK to some other entities)

Comment: TBH I don't understand what will be unique in this case.  You already have FK here.

Comment: Was glad to help! Added as the asnwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `entity.HasOne(d => d.Document).WithMany()` to:

```
entity
    .HasOne(d => d.Document)
    .WithMany(data => data.LinkedDocuments)
```

And you can remove the setup from `entity.HasMany(d => d.LinkedDocuments)` (I would argue that there is no point to setup the same twice).